# How to get the count

Tags: users, wp-user-query

How to get the count of the `WP_User_Query` result
while I use

```
$query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
echo count($query);
```

It returns 1 when there is no user. But I need 0 in that case.

How can I get the count of users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `total_users` property:

```
$query = new WP_User_Query( $args );    
$query->total_users;
```

or `get_total` method:

```
$query = new WP_User_Query( $args );    
$query-> get_total();
```

Docs are your friend: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query